# Java webservice wont start when testing it

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Hey Im trying to make a simple RESTful web service and when I deploy i get this error:

```
SEVERE: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

Im using Netbeans 6.8. Im trying to follow this guide:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Any idea? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That message means you have two different versions of the "ASM" library: one you're using to compile against, and one that's installed in the server. Make sure you use the same version in the server as you're developing with!

The last I knew, they distributed this library in jars with names like `asm-3.0.jar` and `asm-util-3.0.jar`, so that's what you need to search for.